# Using "if not" with multiple string arguments Python

Tags: python, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

Here is what I currently have, which is not working:

```
if "Forwarder" not in shp_name or "T_" not in shp_name or "Grad" not in shp_name:
```

I've also tried:

```
if ("Forwarder", "T_", "Grad") not in shp_name:
```

Samples of the input would be "DS_Forwarder_1" or "DS_Harvester_1". The script proceeds directly to `else` as it's unable to identify any of the above substrings in the primary string.

Comment: Not working how? What do you want to happen and what is happening?

Comment: It's not identifying strings that contain the 3 substrings I've mentioned... and example would be "DS_Forwarder_1"

Comment: So you want it to be `True` if any of the strings are a substring of `shp_name`?

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure, but your current code may not be working the way you expect because you incorrectly negated the expression. The opposite of `if a or b or c` isn't `if not a or not b or not c`, it's `if not a and not b and not c`. See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for more information.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I'm testing your answer at the moment. Really appreciate your help, sorry for wording the question so poorly.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I understand what you are saying, very helpful.

Comment: Can you tell us more how the first line *doesn't work*? Perhaps you can give us sample input and expected results?

Comment: @Pewpewpwnj00, I've changed my answer slightly now I (think I) understand the problem.

Comment: Is that suitable Martijn? It's been quite a while since I've posted. I do believe that both Holloway's and Kevin's comments/answers might be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `any` built in.

```
if any(s in shp_name for s in ("Forwarder", "T_", "Grad")):
    ...
```

This will be true if any of the given strings are present in `shp_name`. You can use `if not any(...` if you want False when one of the strings is present.